# Inserting a node in a binary tree

Tags: java

This is my method so far it's probably wrong but I need to insert a node in a binary tree.

```
public Node insert(Node node, int data)
{
    if (root = null)
     {
        root = insert(data);
     }
     else if (data < node.data)
     {
        node.left = insert(data);
     }
     else if (data > node.data)
     {
        node.right = insert(data);   
     } 
}
```

help? I'm using bluej

Comment: _"it's probably wrong"_ is not a good problem description. If you have a specific question, please ask it. If you're seeing errors/exceptions (which is most likely the case here), post them as well. Thanks.

Comment: How to inserts a node in a binary tree was my question

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Wikipedia page on [**binary search tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree). (Since your nodes are ordered, you are actually implementing a *binary search tree*).

Every common operation - such as [*insertion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Insertion) - is given. The java code is even provided and explained.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as:

```
public void insert(Node node, int data)
{
    if (node == null)
    {
        node = new Node(data, null, null); // create a new leaf node with the data.
    }
    else if (data < node.data)
    {
       insert(node.left, data);
    }
    else if (data > node.data)
    {
       insert(node.right, data);   
    } 
}
```

No need to return anything in my opinion, since your tree is already connected, the function will simply add a new node in the correct position. Just call with:

```
insert(root, data);
```